# Modify static class variable from a different Class/module

Tags: python, selenium

couldnt find concrete answer to my question in other posts so here it goes :

I need to modify a static class variable from a different class/module. I got my LoginPage class with static variable admin

```
class LoginPage(BasePage):

    #Users 
    admin = ["testemail1@gmail.com","Password1234!"]
    basicUser = ["testemail1@gmail.com", "Password1234!"]
```

and i got my profile test class which has uses changepassword method/test :

```
class MyProfileTests(BaseTestCase, LoginPage):
    def test_change_password(self):
        try:
            self.loginAs(self.basicUser)
            MyProfilePage(self.driver).changePassword('Password007$$')
```

and finally changepassword method

```
    def changePassword(self, new_password):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self._change_pw).click()

        password_fields = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='form-group']/*/input")

        password_fields[1].send_keys(new_password)
        self.submit_button.click()

        #Changing password for the LoginPage object
        self._passwordChange(new_password)

    def _passwordChange(self, password):

        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[contains(text(), "Password successfully changed.")]')
            LoginPage.admin[1] = password

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to change actual object which is LoginPage.admin. The idea here is to whenever i use changePassword method that i dont need to manually update the password for the admin/basicuser if i need to login for a differnt test

Comment: Are you sure that there is an element on page with XPath `'//*[contains(text(), "Password successfully changed.")]'`? Maybe you should try to add implicit/explicit wait... P.S. Is there any reason to create class `LoginPage` that contain just two lists? Seems that you make your code too complicated

Comment: hey, first question - yes, because in the system the password is changed, and my loginAs() method no longer works with an old password. 2nd question - i just put the amount of code that i thought was necessary for the question. I got like 4 methods there that have nothing to do with my problem ;)

Comment: No, you don't get it :) I mean, does element with mentioned XPath **really present (available) on page** in moment when you check it? Sometimes page need some time for full rendering (to display all elements), so you should add few second before checking element presence

Comment: Hey, that's what i meant :) I should have mentioned but i have a superclass where i define explicit and implicit waits and this tests inherits from it, so driver waits up to 10 sec for the element to appear if it cant find it, throws NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

It seems what i wanted to do is to dynamically modify a line of code in LoginPage.py, which does not work with my code and will probably need some advanced knowledge. I decided to keep all of the logins in a separate .txt file which solved the problem